# Pusher/PubNub alternative using node.js on Heroku

Tags: android, node.js, heroku, websocket

I would like to build my own **multiplayer game server** using **node.js** and deploy the code on **Heroku**. My question is, if what I describe is possible like that :)

I want players from an **Android** game to be able to connect to a very fast (not necessarily real-time) game server. The game server should be able to group them into rooms (channels) and when they are in rooms, they should be able to **publish and subscribe**. That means, I want the players to exchange game information via the node.js server.

On the server, [**node.js**](http://nodejs.org/) with [**ws**](https://github.com/einaros/ws) shall be used to have a **WebSocket** server listen for client events like this:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });
var clientList = {};

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

    ws['AUTH'] = getGUID();
    clientList[ws['AUTH']] = ws; // ws['AUTH'] has joined the server

    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        for (var clientID in clientList) {
            clientList[clientID].send(message);
        }
    });

    ws.on('close', function() {
        delete clientList[ws['AUTH']]; // ws['AUTH'] has left the server
    }

    ws.send('something');

});

function getGUID() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });   
}
```

On client side, I would like to use [**autobahn.ws**](http://autobahn.ws/android) (which part? WAMP? PubSub or RPC?) to communicate with this game server.

If this works, this is a few lines to have a *very basic* version of what services like Pusher and PubNub offer, right? One would have to add channels, authentication, etc.

If this is possible in with the code above, will it also work on Heroku?

1. What about having **multiple dynos**? Do they share common memory (`clientList`) or do I have to sync between them? How? Using the [cluster API](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)?
2. What number of clients do you *roughly* expect to work on a single dyno? Is 100 concurrent users per dyno expecting too much?

Comment: This is definitely a great start. One of the biggest issues is going to be scaling. You have to setup a system to get heroku nodes to share information with each other. This means setting up a separate instance to collect and sync data between dynos. *Disclosure I work for PubNub*

Comment: @sharpper Thanks for the comment! I like PubNub very much, really! The only thing is that the pricing model and my use case don't work together at all, unfortunately. This is why I have to waive certain features in favor of lower costs. My clients send messages every ~10 seconds only and they change channels very often. This is why I would end up with an incredibly high "peak connection" count although consuming very little power. So I thought setting up node.js for basic WebSocket communication would be more efficient. Syncing data between dynos via PostgreSQL would be too expensive, right?

Comment: It definitely gets expensive fast. It is a large system to build when I'm sure building features into your app is more important. One thing you might want to look into is multiplexing on PubNub. This allows you to connect to multiple channels but counting as only one towards your peak. This might actually save you a lot of money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [WAMP](http://www.wamp.ws/) (via one of the [Autobahn](http://www.autobahn.ws/) libs or [others](http://www.wamp.ws/implementations)) then you could check out [wamp.io](https://github.com/nicokaiser/wamp.io) - a nodejs WAMP implementation.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think using WAMP is mandatory for the described task or can I just implement PubSub-like mechanisms myself, as shown in the question?

Comment: Sure you can .. you will begin to reinvent stuff then and need to implement the required features not only on server, but also for client(s). But of course you can layer an application specific protocol directly onto WebSocket. I am obviously biased on this though;)

Comment: No, I'm totally happy with your answer :) I see that one can't answer this generally, but depending on the use case, Autobahn with WAMP or a custom protocol will be the best solution.